# Why is my mouse pointer keep jumping to the right side of the screen?

Tags: xorg, mouse

My mouse pointer keeps jumping to the right side of the monitor it's on roughly once per minute. I disabled `psmouse` and `usbhid` and the same thing happened, so it's probably not a mouse/touchpad hardware/driver problem. There is nothing in `Xorg.0.log` either.

I have a two monitors set up like this on a Lenovo W541 running Debian Jessie with XFCE:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1600, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
   2560x1600     59.97*+
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.01    60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The graphics cards are set up like this:

```
$ lspci -v |grep -A9 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 221e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at b1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915

--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 221e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
        Memory at b0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at b1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Any idea what can cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that this happens only when I have a Webex session. I used IceWeasel and OpenJDK 7 (NPJP2 plugin was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/IcedTeaPlugin.so`). I installed Firefox 41 and Oracle Java 7 just for Webex, the cursor doesn't jump anymore.